# How can I create simple spheres using CSS?

Tags: css

Is it possible to create a simple sphere using CSS? I'm thinking of something like a 3D sphere.

Comment: something like http://www.bloggermild.com/2012/12/3d-bubbles-using-css3.html ?

Comment: @Gaurav oui! But without the animation

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/prh3hufh/

Comment: “I'm thinking of something like a 3D sphere.” Are there other kinds of spheres? A 2D sphere would be a circle, not a sphere, and a 4D sphere would I guess be a [Borg sphere](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Borg_sphere).

Comment: @PaulD.Waite not my words, someone came along and edited my question

Comment: @TreyTaylor: aha, very true. Your original question was “Is it possible to spherize a canvas using CSS?” I’m not clear what that means either.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I was refering to spherize, the effect from Photoshop but applying it to a <canvas> html5 tag :)

Comment: @TreyTaylor: Ah, gotcha. Well, that makes sense. You can always edit your question again to make its intended meaning clear, if the current state doesn’t do that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I didn't love the answers and comments already provided; too much code for a simple sphere in html - css. You can simply do:

```
<div class = "sphere">Test</div>
```

The CSS:

```
body {
    background: #333;
    }

.sphere {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    line-height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
    margin: 100px auto;
    /* The magic are those 2 lines: */
    border-radius: 100%;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 80px #FFF;
    }
```

> [Simple JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/franciscop/4ouzfyjm/16/)

Then I wanted to challenge myself and so some more complex stuff. This is the result:

[image: Spheres]

The HTML:

```
<div class = "sphere a">This</div>
<div class = "sphere b">Is</div>
<div class = "sphere c">A</div>
<div class = "sphere d">Test</div>
```

The CSS:

```
body {
    background: #333;
}
.sphere {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    line-height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    margin: -100px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 80px #FFF;
    color: #FFF;
}
.a {
    top: 10%;
    left: 20%;
}
.b {
    top: 30%;
    left: 60%;
}
.c {
    top: 60%;
    left: 40%;
}
.d {
    top: 80%;
    left: 70%;
}
```

> [Full JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/franciscop/4ouzfyjm/15/)

Comment: Good answer - however, I recommend a `border-radius: 100%` instead of the fixed size. Remove a point of failure/thing to think about.

Comment: Thanks @Kjeld, fixed. Any other recommendation?

Comment: Don't think so. I'd personally have `class="sphere"` instead of `class = "sphere"`, but that's rather nitpicky and not conceptual.

Answer (score 10):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/prh3hufh/5/)**

css

```
.demo-container {  
 height:300px;  
 overflow:hidden;  
 display:block;  
 position:relative;  
 /* CSS3 Gradient */  
 background: rgb(125,126,125);  
 background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);  
 background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(125,126,125,1) 0%, rgba(14,14,14,1) 100%);  
 background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%,rgba(125,126,125,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(14,14,14,1)));  
 background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(125,126,125,1) 0%,rgba(14,14,14,1) 100%);  
 background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(125,126,125,1) 0%,rgba(14,14,14,1) 100%);  
 background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(125,126,125,1) 0%,rgba(14,14,14,1) 100%);  
 background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center,  rgba(125,126,125,1) 0%,rgba(14,14,14,1) 100%);  
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#7d7e7d', endColorstr='#0e0e0e',GradientType=1 );  
 }  
.bubble1, .bubble2, .bubble3, .bubble4 {  
 position:absolute;  
 display:block;  
 /* CSS3 Box Shadow */  
 box-shadow:0 20px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset 0px 10px 30px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);  
 -webkit-box-shadow:0 20px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset 0px 10px 30px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);  
 -moz-box-shadow:0 20px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset 0px 10px 30px 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);  
 /* CSS3 Border Radius */  
 border-radius:50%;  
 -webkit-border-radius:50%;  
 -moz-border-radius:50%;  
 /* CSS3 Transition */  
 -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;  
 -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;  
 -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;  
 transition: all .5s ease-in-out;  
 }  
.bubble1 {  
 width:100px;  
 height:100px;  
 top:20%;  
 left:50%;  
 }   
.bubble2 {  
 width:200px;  
 height:200px;  
 left:20%;  
 top:10%;  
 }  
.bubble3 {  
 width:150px;  
 height:150px;  
 left:50%;  
 top:40%;  
 }  
.bubble4 {  
 width:90px;  
 height:90px;  
 left:70%;  
 top:15%;  
 }  
/* .bubble1:hover {  
 margin-top:30px;  
 width:90px;  
 }  
.bubble2:hover {  
 margin-left:20px;  
 height:190px;  
 }  
.bubble3:hover {  
 margin-top:60px;  
 width:160px;  
 }  
.bubble4:hover {  
 margin-left:50px;  
 height:100px;  
 }  */

/* remove below codes if you don't wish to have the texts "3D Bubbles" */
.demo-text{  
 position:absolute;  
 bottom:20px;  
 right:15px;  
 font-size:36px;  
 color:#666;  
 text-shadow:0 2px 0 #000;  
 }
```

html

```
<div class="demo-container">  
 <span class="bubble1"></span>  
 <span class="bubble2"></span>  
 <span class="bubble3"></span>  
 <span class="bubble4"></span>  
 <div class="demo-text">3D Bubbles</div> <!-- remove this div if you don't wish to have the texts "3D Bubbles" --> 
</div>
```

[Refer](http://www.bloggermild.com/2012/12/3d-bubbles-using-css3.html)

Comment: +1, looks more like a sphere than a simple circular gradient as in Francisco's answer.